# Objective-C HTML parsing. Get all text between tags

Tags: html, objective-c, parsing, hpple

I am using [hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) to try and grab a torrent description from ThePirateBay. Currently, I'm using this code:

```
NSString *path = @"//div[@id='content']/div[@id='main-content']/div/div[@id='detailsouterframe']/div[@id='detailsframe']/div[@id='details']/div[@class='nfo']/pre/node()";
NSArray *nodes = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:path];
for (TFHppleElement * element in nodes) {
    NSString *postid = [element content];
    if (postid) {
        [texts appendString:postid];
    }
}
```

This returns just the plain text, and not any of the URL's for screenshots. Is there anyway to get all links and other tags, not just plain text? 
The piratebay is fomratted like so:

```
<pre>
    <a href="http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/8292/itskindofafunnystory201.jpg" rel="nofollow">
    http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/8292/itskindofafunnystory201.jpg</a>
More texts about the file
</pre>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `@"//div[@id='content']/div[@id='main-content']/div/div[@id='detailsouterframe']/div[@id='detailsframe']/div[@id='details']/div[@class='nfo']/pre/text()`? Does it help?

Comment: It returns the same thing

Comment: Then please some more html or a link because with the snippet you gave I got it working ... I used the snippet with `@"//pre/text()"`. I think there is something else wrong with your path

Comment: The site: http://thepiratebay.sx/torrent/8433464/Parker.2013.BRRip.XviD-S4A will return all the text in the description, but not the links. like "Blah blah Screenshots: /and no links to the screenshots", with what you posted.

Comment: You want the links to the screenshots? like `http://leetleech.org/images/42024611449329122742.png`?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what I want

Comment: All right, have a look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an easy job and you did it almost correctly!

What you want is the content (or an attribute) of the `a`-tag, so you need to tell the parser that you want it.

Just change your `XPath` to

```
@"//div[@id='content']/div[@id='main-content']/div/div[@id='detailsouterframe']/div[@id='detailsframe']/div[@id='details']/div[@class='nfo']/pre/a"
```

*(You missed the `a` at the very end and you do not need `node()`)*

**Output:**

> http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1904996/
>     http://leetleech.org/images/65823608764828593230.png
>     http://leetleech.org/images/44748070481477652927.png
>     http://leetleech.org/images/42024611449329122742.png

If you only want the screenshot URLs you can do something like

```
NSMutableArray *screenshotURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (int i = 1; i < nodes.count; i++) {
    [screenshotURLs addObject:nodes[i]];
}
```